# Filtering datasheet view in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: web-part, filter, view, datasheet

I want to create a filter on Multiline Text Column inside a Datasheet View by means of out of the box features. Is it possible to provision such a feature so that when I click on the dropdown on such column, it would show the values for that column in a scroll down panel, similar to how it shows them for other standard type of columns.

If it is not possible, then would it be possible to create a filter web part (like Text Filter web part) so that when I search for a  multiline text column value in the filter box, that specific row would appear in the Datasheet View?

Answer (score 1):

I fear that the Datasheet view doesn't support web part connections nor filtering (made exception for the manual filters a user can select from the dropdowns on the columns headers, which are a different thing).